# How to create bipartite network in igraph with duplicate vertices names

Tags: r, csv, social-networking, bipartite

I want to create a bipartite network that connects NFL teams with the colleges they drafted players from. I have 1955 rows in my data - one row for each player. I have two csv files (edge.csv and node.csv). The edge data is set up as such:

```
Team      College
Arizona   Alabama
Arizona   Alabama
Arizona   Arizona St.
Arizona   Arizona St.
Arizona   Auburn
```

And the node data is set up as such:

```
Team     Player   No.   type
Arizona  A        1     TRUE
Arizona  B        2     TRUE
Arizona  C        3     TRUE
Arizona  D        4     TRUE
Arizona  E        5     TRUE
```

The other variables in my node data are Age, Position, Games Played, Games Started, Weight, Height, Birthdate, Pro Years Played, Team Drafted, Round Drafted, Overall Pick, Year Drafted.

And then I added the colleges to the Team column starting at row 1956 and filled in the type as FALSE, all other variables across are NA.

When I try to convert these files to a graph in RStudio, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in graph.data.frame(edge.df, node.df, directed = FALSE) : 
Duplicate vertex names
```

which I assume is because names of teams and colleges repeat, but with this network, that is unavoidable and the entire purpose of looking at this data. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer for this? I'm having the same issue.